# Best way to run same rule twice with different params

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake, vcf-variant-call-format, bcftools

I'm using `bcftools consensus` to extract haplotypes from a vcf file. 
Given the input files:

```
A.sorted.bam
B.sorted.bam
```

The following output files are created:

```
A.hap1.fna
A.hap2.fna
B.hap1.fna
B.hap2.fna
```

I currently have two rules to do this. They differ only by the numbers 1 and 2 in the output files and shell command. Code:

```
rule consensus1:
    input:
        vcf="variants/phased.vcf.gz",
        tbi="variants/phased.vcf.gz.tbi",
        bam="alignments/{sample}.sorted.bam"
    output:
        "haplotypes/{sample}.hap1.fna"
    params:
        sample="{sample}"
    shell:
        "bcftools consensus -i -s {params.sample} -H 1 -f {reference_file} {input.vcf} > {output}"

rule consensus2:
    input:
        vcf="variants/phased.vcf.gz",
        tbi="variants/phased.vcf.gz.tbi",
        bam="alignments/{sample}.sorted.bam"
    output:
        "haplotypes/{sample}.hap2.fna"
    params:
        sample="{sample}"
    shell:
        "bcftools consensus -i -s {params.sample} -H 2 -f {reference_file} {input.vcf} > {output}"
```

While this code works, it seems that there should be a better, more pythonic way to do this using only one rule. Is it possible to collapse this into one rule, or is my current method the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use wildcards for haplotypes 1 and 2 in `rule all`. [See here](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets) to learn more about adding targets via `rule all`

```
reference_file = "ref.txt"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("haplotypes/{sample}.hap{hap_no}.fna",
                   sample=["A", "B"], hap_no=["1", "2"])

rule consensus1:
    input:
        vcf="variants/phased.vcf.gz",
        tbi="variants/phased.vcf.gz.tbi",
        bam="alignments/{sample}.sorted.bam"
    output:
        "haplotypes/{sample}.hap{hap_no}.fna"
    params:
        sample="{sample}",
        hap_no="{hap_no}"
    shell:
        "bcftools consensus -i -s {params.sample} -H {params.hap_no} \
               -f {reference_file} {input.vcf} > {output}"
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I needed. Using wildcards with the target rule is very powerful. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You don't even need to reassign `hap_no` to a `param`. Wildcards are directly accessible from the rule body, in this instance, as `wildcards.hap_no`.

Comment: @KirillG True. But it's a habit of mine to keep all parameters I use in one place for easy readability.